# Python 3 pyAutoGUI - I can't use screenshot functions

Tags: python, automation, screenshot, pyautogui

I tried an import from the documentation:

```
import pyautgui
pyautogui.click(pyautogui.locateOnScreen("select.png"))
```

and I get these errors in line 2:

```
File "C:\log\WinPython-64bit-3.5.4.0Qt5\python-3.5.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 267, in locateOnScreen
screenshotIm = screenshot(region=None) # the locateAll() function must handle cropping to return accurate coordinates, so don't pass a region here.

File "C:\log\WinPython-64bit-3.5.4.0Qt5\python-3.5.4.amd64\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 314, in _screenshot_win32
im = ImageGrab.grab()

NameError: name 'ImageGrab' is not defined
```

Could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to import ImageGrab

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
```

Comment: well PIL is now obsolete in Python 3! and pyautogui needs python3. So I have installed Pillow version 4.2.1 when I had this problem. Notice that all functions from pyautogui are ok except those which are making screenshots. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: After some research, I found that effectively Pillow replace PIL library but must be imported like this "import PIL"!!. So skr you were perfectly right if you have Pillow installed instead of PIL